# What happens if you scry a target that's invisible?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, invisibility, divination

What happens if you scry a target with either scrying or greater scrying while the subject is under the effects of a (Greater) invisibility spell?

This is assuming the target fails her will save and the scry will actually go through as it would normally do to a visible person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The spell would work, but could confuse the watcher.**

> If the save fails, you can see and hear the subject and the subject’s immediate surroundings (approximately 10 feet in all directions of the subject). If the subject moves, the sensor follows at a speed of up to 150 feet.

The sensor itself would be created.  Think of scry as revealing the location of the target, but doing nothing to the target itself.  If you also had see invisibility available to yourself, you would also see the "invisible" creature.

You would see the location and hear what is going on, but likely one may think the spell had failed.  If the invisible creature moved, the scrying device would move with them.  Scrying itself does not specifically require line of sight in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, this goes in line with what I expected, I just wasn't sure.

Comment: Is this your belief or do you have some sort of citation that the sensor can detect invis?  Belief by omission?

Comment: The target of the spell is the target itself and is biased on you knowledge and familiarity of the subject itself.   A scrying sensor is created at the targets location and you can see what the sensor sees.  The subject is only the landing location of the remote sensor.  It doesn't matter what condition they are in unless they have scrying protections, the sensor is created.  If they are scryed on in a completely dark room, the sensor only shows blackness without showing the target...  if they are invisible, it shows an empty room.  The scrying device is just a "camera"

Answer (score 3):

**The spell would work & the caster should immediately know something is up & easily figure out what it is!**

---

The spell would work, and the caster shouldn't be confused for more than a second or 2 if at all.

If the spell fails (target succeeds it's saving throw) nothing happens.  The caster knows they failed and they can't try again (on this target) for 24hrs. They can, however, cast another spell targeting any known friends/party members known to travel with them if they have such information.

If the caster is able to see an area but simply can't see the target of their scry they should know the spell succeeded and that they just can't see them for some reason. (this is similar to a dark room, the caster knows their target is there they just can't see them)

Remember

> [Scrying](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/scrying.htm) is a 4th level spell (minimum CL=7) while 
>  
>   [Greater Scrying](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/scryingGreater.htm) is a 7th level spell (minimum CL=13) and 
>   [Invisibility](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/invisibility.htm) is a 2nd level spell (minimum CL=3).

Unless the caster had a recent run-in with an illithid he should have an idea that other magics are in play.  To be 100% true to the rules you could have the caster roll a spellcraft check to identify that it's an invisibility spell (DC=22 for Invisibility or DC=24 for [Greater Invisibility](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/invisibilityGreater.htm)) but I'm also pretty sure a caster of this level has *"seen"* Invisibility cast before.

Additionally, there is a 5% per CL (minimum 35% chance @level 7) that detect Magic/law/chaos/evil/good & message) function through the scry. If successful, these spells will enable the caster to further identify what magics are at play and where the target is at, if not what they're actively doing.

*Note: corrected caster level to reflect wizard vs sorcerer

Comment: Wizards can cast level 2 spells at third level. so CL3. but I get the point you're making. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Hyfnae Thx! I knew those numbers looked wrong! I accidentally referenced the Sorcerer instead of Wizard tables. It's been updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

From the *Scrying* spell:

> As with all divination (scrying) spells, the sensor has your full visual acuity, including any magical effects.

So, I don't think the *Scrying* spell changes anything about your vision (so for example, you keep your Darkvision while scrying into a dark room). As others have mentioned, you would definitely still get a sensor at their location. However, there's also nothing stopping you as a Bard/Wizard/Sorcerer from having a *See Invsibility* spell ready to go. *Detect Magic/Alignment/etc* is also an option for most casters, but unless it's *Greater Scrying* you still have the chance to fail.